# Start python script on startup - python script runs after login on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, startup, boot

I would like to run a python script directly on startup of the raspberry pi. I can execute the script by calling /home/pi/scripts/script.py. Now I tried to add the script to /etc/rc.local or /etc/profile or start it with systemd. For all cases the script is only executed after a connection to the pi via SSH and a login to the pi.

Therefore I would like to know who I could execute the script on boot (startup) without having to do a login?

Comment: Check this link- https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: I already tried these methods. But it requires a login after boot. Then it works. But it needs to run without a login.

Comment: You can try to setup autologin `sudo raspi-config` or maybe editing the config manually https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with systemd and unit files.
First read this:
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files]
You probably used multi-user.target as wanted-by but that is too late.
You could use

```
sudo systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

to see which .targets might be better for your need.For example basic.target looks good.
You can of course also state in the unit file explicitly that your unit (.service) needs to be loaded before for example ifup@eth0.service
Use `sudo systemctl list-units`  or `sudo systemctl list-unit-files` to see everything that in this respect is going on.